# Apache mod_rewrite, force https, forward from root folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I asked a question about this yesterday but I am still having trouble with my httpd.conf.

What I would like to happen is this:

- User requests `http://www.mysite.com/` or `mysite.com`, etc. They are then redirected to `https://www.mysite.com/shop/`
- I would also like to make sure that any request under the `/shop` subdirectory is rewritten to HTTPS as well, even if the user types in `http://www.mysite.com/shop/help/` it would be rewritten as `https://www.mysite.com/shop/help/`

Here is my configuration right now, which isn't working.

```
Listen *:443 https
Listen *:80 http

<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^(shop/.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shop/$1 [NC,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shop/ [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLAppName QIBM_HTTP_SERVER_ZENDSVR
    SetEnv HTTPS_PORT 443
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shop/ [NC,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not working, as in nothing works or are there some things that behave as expected?

Comment: Not working as expected. For instance if I enter https://www.mysite.com/ it will try to load index.php which doesn't exist, so I had to create one with a header command to redirect to https://www.mysite.com/shop/ I also still have the issue with some urls not being forced to HTTPS. If they are at https://www.mysite.com/shop/ or any subfolders and they change it to http://www.mysite.com/shop/ I would like it to redirect them to the HTTPS version of the site. Right now it will just accept the url they change and load the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure mod_rewrite kicks in when your server receives a request. For example, to redirect all requests from your HTTP host to your HTTPS server

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shop/ [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Then try

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/?shop/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shop/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shop/ [R=301,L]

    # other directives
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/shop/ [R=301,L]

    # other directives
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So I can have two <VirtualHost *:80> rule containers?

Comment: @Bead As far as I know, not if you are in a IP based hosting as your configuration suggests. My first example is meant to replace your current `<VirtualHost *:80>` to test if mod_rewrite effectively works. You can skip it and directly try the second code block.

Comment: Ok, I will try this when I am able to reset the server. Thank you.